# Get List Size in JS controller using lightning web component

Tags: html, lightning-web-components, js-controller

I need the size of a List, which was passed from the Apex controller to the JavaScript controller and built using Lightning web component.

Below is the code I am trying:

```
@wire(getObjectDetails)
wiredResult(data,error) { 
    if(data){
        console.log('DateOfRun-->'+data);
        console.log('values-->'+data.length);
    } else if(error){
        console.log('error -->'+error);   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get where you're trying to output data.length? :-)

Comment: values-->undefined

Comment: and what about data? what is that returning?

Comment: [Object Object]

Comment: I need the size of the list, Because when there is a record in Object, I want to show some template,and when there were no records I would like to show another template, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[object Object] is the default toString representation of an object in javascript.

You can try with below code to get length. It should work in your case.

```
@track results = [];
@track totalContact;
@wire(getObjectDetails)
wiredResult(data,error) { 
    if(data){
        this.results= JSON.stringify(data);
   //  add this condition 
        this.totalContact = this.results?.length ?? 0;
        console.log('total no of object-->',this.totalContact);
    } else if(error){
        console.log('error -->',error);   
    }
}
```